# Node18 Lambda append formdata from s3 bucket failed to execute

Tags: lambda, aws-s3-client

All, I'm trying to take an S3 Bucket object and FormData.Append it, but it keeps telling me that Parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

I can easily go the other way, take data from a callback and post it to S3, just not the outbound path I'm trying to do.

Environment:   AWS, Lambda, NodeJS18x.  (The NodeJs18 part is kind of the important part here, Compliance wants me to use the most recent LTS version.).

```
console.info("Preparing to get S3 object.");
let command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
const item = await client.send(command);
        
console.log(data);
        
let form = new FormData();
form.append("media", data, { filename: srcKey });
```

I also have tried it this way:

```
console.info("Preparing to get S3 object.");
      
const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    
let form = new FormData();
form.append("media", data.Body, { filename: srcKey });
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?